# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier issue

Tags: solidity, remix, error

Can't figure out this error. Please help!

```
"DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. (bool success, ) = recipient.call; value; amount ;(""); ^---^"





function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");

        // solhint-disable-next-line avoid-low-level-calls, avoid-call-value
        (bool success, ) = recipient.call; value; amount ;("");
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This line makes no sense:

```
(bool success, ) = recipient.call; value; amount ;("");
```

Change to:

```
(bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }("");
```

Note that using raw calls - i.e. `.call()` - isn't recommended. The author of the code seems to know this, as they've explicitly added the `avoid-low-level-calls` comment to disable the associated compiler warning.